# Why COM class need to be public if non creatable?

Tags: c#, com, activex, com-interop, activexobject

I've created a COM wrapper for a C# library, following Microsoft design rules and everything seemed to work well when consuming via scripting (VB script) or via TLB C++.

Recently we tried to use via ActiveX in Internet Explorer 11, and only some functionalities were available. It took some hours to identify the culprit.
So I have a factory class to give access to a particular database, and I expose both interface and class, so the COM user can create an instance object of the factory:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("...")]
public interface IFactory
{
    IDbAccess CreateDbAccess(string param);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("....")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("Company.Factory")]
public class Factory: IFactory
{
    public Factory()
    { }

    public virtual IDbAccess CreateDbAccess(string param)
    {
        return new DbAccess(param);
    }
}
```

when it comes to actually create an access to the DB, the user should call: `factory.CreateDbAccess(...)` and then use the IDbAccess interface. This method returns `undefined` in javascript.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("...")]
public interface IDbAccess
{
    string Read();
}

internal class DbAccess: IDbAccess
{
    public string Read();
}
```

If I turn the `DbAccess` class to public and apply the `ComVisibile(true)` attribute, instead it works.
Can anyone explain why? I thought the interface was enough to use it (and it seems so in VBScripting).

Thanks

Comment: That's .NET rules, there's no "why". A class must be ComVisible to support any COM interface.

Comment: @SimonMourier but in .NET if I provide a factory which creates the object for you and returns it in forms of an interface, the class can be internal.

Comment: Yes, it could work like you want but it just doesn't. NET decides unilaterally that you must have a public class to use COM.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for clarifying. It seems a bizarre idea to allow internal classes when allowing late binding. I'd thought at least a warning or info from the build! BTW: do you have a reference? I found little documentation on COM + .NET